# Почему Всегда выводит True

Tags: python-3.x, vkontakte-api

Проблема в том что когда я ввожу пароль(Правильный) он Выводит True и неправильный(Пароль) он тоже Выводит True Почему и как это исправить ??

```
def vk_auth():
    login = 'login'
    password = 'password'
    vk = vk_api.VkApi(login,password)
    try:
        vk.auth()  
    except vk_api.AuthorizationError as error_msg:
        print('Password not') 
    else:
        print('password True')     


    return vk
vk_auth()
```

Comment: Предлагаю таким способом авторизовываться и проверять: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/b7c011102a7d47b2994c0ce9342f86fcf835e580/vk_api__examples/wall.post%20hello%20world.py

Answer (score 1):

Исправь эту строчку

```
 except vk_api.AuthorizationError as error_msg:
```

на

```
except vk_api.AuthError as error_msg:
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

vk это элемент класса, а не статус авторизации. Даже при неправильном логине или пароле он все равно существует и вернет True

```
def vk_auth():
    login = 'login'
    password = 'password'
    vk = vk_api.VkApi(login,password)
    try:
        vk.auth()  
    except vk_api.AuthorizationError as error_msg:
        result = True 
        print('Password not') 
    else:
        result = False
        print('password True')     
    return result
vk_auth()
```